# Linq to return a value based on another value in an object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object as such:

```
{
  "orderSummaries": [
    {
      "orderTypeId": "8b3206ed-0ea0-41bc-8d4b-b39882f81019",
      "name": "DefaultOrder",
      "description": "default order"
    },
    {
      "orderTypeId": "6ebc76dd-1d0f-4292-84f2-f95b71f821cb",
      "name": "Loan purchase",
      "description": "loan purchase order"
    }
    ]}
```

I am trying to use a linq query to return the 'orderTypeId' of the order that has a particular name.. but i can't go further

```
e.g orders.orderSummaries.Select(x => x.Name == request.name)//this will be Loan purchase
// return the order orderTypeId value with the name of the request variable
```

Not sure how to do this in linq?

Comment: `Select` -> `Where` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) instead of [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) to filter out the list and then [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) to project only `orderTypeId`

```
var result = orders.orderSummaries
     .Where(x => x.Name == request.name)  //Filter orderSummaries based on request.name
     .Select(x => x.orderTypeId); //Project only orderTypeId instead of entire orderSummary object
```

---

> [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0): Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

In your case, predicate is `x.Name == request.name`

> [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0): Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

In your case, new form is IEnumerable of `orderTypeId`(s) instead of entire entire IEnumerable of `orderSummaries`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using both `Where` and `Select` - the first is for filtering the values you need, and the second is for projecting the properties you want to return:

```
 orders
    .orderSummaries
    .Where(x => x.Name == request.name)
    .Select(x => x.orderTypeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do.

```
  var orderTypeId = orders
     .orderSummaries
     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == request.name)?
     .orderTypeId;
```

if you're sure the `Name` is unique. otherwise:

```
 var orderTypeIds = orders
         .orderSummaries
         .Where(x => x.Name == request.name)
         .Select(x => x.orderTypeId);
```

Comment: @GuruStron No, it will not, but it's kinda hard to see it the way it's written now -Bargros is using `?.` after `FirstOrDefault` (though I'm not sure the compiler will allow to write it with a line break between `?` and `.`)

Comment: @GuruStron this won't throw, instead if the order doesn't exist then `orderTypeId` will be null `)?`.

Comment: However note that it will only return one value, so you're either assuming the names are unique or the OP just wants the "first" name (that being said, "first" as per what order?)

Comment: @Bargros yes, sorry, missed the null-conditional operator.